# There a error when sorting the arrays by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I had write a function to arrange the arrays by the last character,
but I found that there are error when the function run to `mushrooms5` and `Sauce6`. Can anyone help me solve the error cause I can't find it?

Thanks.

```
var Dish_name = [
    "Layered_Dip2",
    "Pumpkin_Deviled_Eggs1",
    "Chinese_fried_egg_noodles_with_shredded_pork_mushrooms5",
    "Stir_fried_Clams_with_Garlic_and_Black_Bean_Sauce6",
    "Rosewater_Panna_Cotta4",
    "Marshmallow_Rabbit3",
]

var Dish_show_name = [
    "<b>Layered Dip</b>",
    "<b>Pumpkin Deviled Eggs</b>",
    "<b>Chinese Fried Egg Noodles with Shredded Pork Mushrooms</b>",
    "<b>Stir fried Clams with Garlic and Black Bean Sauce</b>",
    "<b>Rosewater Panna Cotta</b>",
    "<b>Marshmallow Rabbit</b>",
]

var Dish_url = [
    "http://3.1m.yt/BqHJBVM.jpg",
    "http://4.1m.yt/2yq6CpE.png",
    "http://3.1m.yt/k-owd2.jpg",
    "http://4.1m.yt/zvcLufM.png",
    "http://3.1m.yt/Fw9Wdcw.png",
    "http://1.1m.yt/INLaIN-.jpg"
]    

$("#cook").click(function() {
    var i, j, temp, temp2, temp3;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j < 6; i++) {
            if (Dish_name[i].slice(-1) > Dish_name[j].slice(-1)) {
                temp = Dish_name[i];
                temp2 = Dish_show_name[i];
                temp3 = Dish_url[i];
                Dish_name[i] = Dish_name[j];
                Dish_show_name[i] = Dish_show_name[j];
                Dish_url[i] = Dish_url[j];
                Dish_name[j] = temp;
                Dish_show_name[j] = temp2;
                Dish_url[j] = temp3;
                alert(Dish_name[i]);
                alert(Dish_name[j]);
                alert(Dish_name[i].slice(-1));
                alert(Dish_name[j].slice(-1));
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: what is the error? what is the problem?

Comment: @Dekel It's properly that `m` is sorted after `S` because it's lowercase.

Comment: @Dekel I think that is the third one will match with second one then after sorting 1,2,5,6,4,3....
but I dont know how to fix it...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your bubble-sort; the inner loop should be:

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    for (j = i + 1; j < 6; j++) {
             ^^^^^         ^
```

The inner loop should run from the next element after the current `i`, not starting at `1` every time round. And I've just noticed that the inner loop also increments `i`, not `j`!

Comment: You beat me to it! =)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good implementation of the bubble sort in JavaScript, and it's a bit more compact and fixes the variable error in your loop.

```
function bubble(arr) {
      var len = arr.length;

      for (var i = 0; i < len ; i++) {
        for(var j = 0 ; j < len - i - 1; j++){ // there was an error in your code here
        if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
          // swap
          var temp = arr[j];
          arr[j] = arr[j+1];
          arr[j + 1] = temp;
        }
       }
      }
      return arr;
    }

document.write(bubble([1,9,2,3,7,6,4,5,5]));
```